# Clash of Clan App accidentally deleted

Tags: clash-of-clans

I accidentally deleted my Clash of Clans App. I went to Playstore to get a new App so that I could get access to my village and clan . Hoewever, now I cannot get access with the new icon. It says: "Clash of Clans has stopped" What should  I do? I cannot loose my village. I put massive effort , time and money into it

Comment: Did you stored your village with Google Play Games? Try to go to the CoC settings, locate Google Play Games, and click on it, to login with your Play Games account, to get your village back.

Comment: Elki42. I cannot get to the CoC settings because I cannot get into the game at all. It keepd on saying; C o C has stopped. I cannot get any further

Answer (score 0):

If it has stopped, let it close. And re-open it and try to login, complete the intro,then click the gear (settings) and click login with google (if you were logged in with google) and if you were not signed in at all, then I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What do you mean by " complete the intro"?

Comment: The tutorial, when typing up an answer I forgot what it was called xD